# How to retrieve the datasource used by a persistence unit programmatically

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

...without actually reading and parsing the `persistence.xml`

I can retrieve the name of the persistence unit of an `EntityManager` using the [properties of it's factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getProperties%28%29). I can retrieve the available datasources using the [jboss-as-controller-client](http://www.paykin.info/java/add-datasource-programaticaly-cli-jboss-7/). But I have found no API that would give me the datasource of a particular `EntityManager`.

A `String` with a name would be enough.

Thank you

I am working with Hibernate 4.0.1.Final over  JPA 2 on a JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

EDIT: and I would like to avoid straying from JPA to Hibernate APIs if possible.

EDIT : Augusto's solution worked, I have some notes on details: The casting of the EM didn't work because of a `ClassCastException`:(`org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager cannot be cast to org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl`), but it worked for the retrieved factory. So I omitted step 1.

I also could not find a way to retrieve the name of the datasource from the instance. So I had to content myself with the catalog name: `connectionProvider.getConnection().getCatalog();`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to:

1. cast the `EntityManager` to `EntityManagerImpl` (the Hibernate implementation)
2. call `getFactory()`
3. cast the `EntityManagerFactory` to `HibernateEntityManagerFactory`
4. call `getSessionFactory()` and cast it to `SessionFactoryImpl`
5. call `getConnectionProvider()` and cast it to the correct implementation. You can see the implementations [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html). I'll assume that it's a `DatasourceConnectionProvider`
6. call `getDataSource()` and you're done.

Unfortunately, you must use the Hibernate API, as there's no way to retrieve the DataSource using the JPA API.

Comment: Thanks, Augusto, looks promising. I'm still fighting my way out of the dependency hell, trying to find out which hibernate artifacts jboss actually provides to reference them in my pom. I'll accept once I see the light

Comment: Another strike against JPA in my opinion... This process, while correct is way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: getConnectionProvider() now seems to have been removed from the API.

Comment: In my case there is `C3P0ConnectionProvider` (not `DatasourceConnectionProvider`), that dont have `getDataSource()` method. By reading source code, find this solution: `sessionFactory.getConnectionProvider().unwrap(DataSource.class)`

Answer (score 20):

In a Spring environment you can use this:

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryInfo;
...

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public DataSource getDataSourceFromHibernateEntityManager() {
   EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
   return info.getDataSource();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I am using hibernate 5.2.10.Final and the following worked for me:

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    //...
    public static DataSource getDataSource(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    ConnectionProvider cp = ((SessionFactory) entityManagerFactory).getSessionFactoryOptions()
            .getServiceRegistry()
            .getService(ConnectionProvider.class);
    return cp.unwrap(DataSource.class);
    }
```

What you need is just to pass entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory() to this method (For my case, I have multiple factories. Then I can use this method to get the datasource for any of them when needed).

Answer (score 9):

If you just want the name of the datasource and that datasource name was supplied per JPA means, you should be able to get that information via:

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get( "javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" );
```

or

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get( "javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource" );
```

depending on how you defined the datasource.

Comment: Does not work for me :( both queries return `null`. Do you happen to have a source for those property names?

Comment: A source?  Not sure what you mean.  The JPA spec defines them.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I thought I can try some other properties. Have found the spot - §9.4.3 Persistence Unit Properties. As I have understood it, since setting these properties is not required, they may remain unset by the provider. Could that be the case for Hibernate?

Comment: Have iterated over all the properties of the EMF. The *DataSource properties are not set, `hibernate.session_factory_name` is the closest thing to what I want, but it's only the PU name.

Comment: This is something I think *should* work.  If it does not I'd like to make sure it does.  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8121  Sorry, I thought it was that way already.

Comment: This property works in Hibernate (I've tried it with Hibernate 4.1): `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get("hibernate.connection.datasource");`

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do this in order to run Flyway migrations.  I wasn't able to retrieve the DataSource using Augusto's method, but I was able to recreate the data source by retrieving the url, username & password from the SessionFactory properties:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory).getSessionFactory();
Properties properties = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getProperties();
String url = (String) properties.get("hibernate.connection.url");
String username = (String) properties.get("hibernate.connection.username");
String password = (String) properties.get("hibernate.connection.password");
```

Comment: No, no. Usage of a different `DataSource` (even pointing to the same database) can lead to very subtle problems.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
Session s = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory=s.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider cp=((SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory).getConnectionProvider();Connection connection=cp.getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData dbmetadata= connection.getMetaData();
String dtsource=dbmetadata.getUserName();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.x

This is how I'm getting a connection from the persistence pool:

```
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl;

public Connection getConnection(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws SQLException
{
    final EntityManagerFactoryImpl hibernateEmf = (EntityManagerFactoryImpl) emf;
    return hibernateEmf.getSessionFactory().getServiceRegistry().getService(ConnectionProvider.class).getConnection();
}
```

The `emf` parameter is JPA's standard `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`, typically acquired globally using:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit-name");
```

or by injection:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistence-unit-name")
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) 
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties()
            .get(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_JTA_DATASOURCE);
```

You can retrieve datasoure with hibernate. Tested with Hibernate 5.3

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context to describe how your answer address the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

in SpringBoot environment you can use the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

private HikariDataSource getDataSourceFromHibernateEntityManager() {
    EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
    return (HikariDataSource) info.getDataSource();
}

public String getDataSourceProperties() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = getDataSourceFromHibernateEntityManager();
    return "DataSource properties:" +
            "URL: " + dataSource.getJdbcUrl() + "\n" +
            "Default Schema: " + dataSource.getPoolName() + "\n" +
            "Driver Class Name: " + dataSource.getDriverClassName() + "\n" +
            "Username: " + dataSource.getUsername() + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what helped me. I use HikariCP but I don't think it matters.

Basically what needs to be done is

1. find a service registry
2. get service by `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider` class
3. unwrap it to `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Service registry can be retrieved from EntityManager

```
((SessionImpl) em).getFactory().getServiceRegistry()
```

or from EntityManagerFactory directly

```
((SessionFactoryImpl) entityManagerFactory).getServiceRegistry()
```